# Group queryset by month in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am grouping a queryset by months with following code

```
Model.objects.extra(select={'month': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')}).values('month')
```

It works fine but when the table has objects where the field `date` is `None` it results in `OperationalError` with message `user-defined function raised exception`.

Shouldn't this error handling be in the django method `date_trunc_sql()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the model instances with date=None from your queryset.

```
Model.objects.exclude(date__isnull=True).extra(select={'month': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')}).values('month')
```

The error can't be caught in the `date_trunc_sql()` method -- the method is called an returns a string before the queryset is evaluated.